# Angular 5 - Data Loop not showing multiple records on sub item

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get data to display a parent container and child items of the parent container to show.

Here is the data:

```
constructor() {
    this.datas = [
      {
        title: 'Container 1',
        'resizable': true,
        childItems: [
          {'item': 'item 1'},
          {'item': 'item 2'}
        ]
      }
    ];
```

And here is the code to get the data:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of datas">

  <div [ngWidgetContainer]="data">
    <div [ngWidget]="data.childItems">List Child Items belonging to this Container</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The problem with the data is that it should be listing 2 childItems but it's only listing 1.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why don’t you need a second ngFor? Is there a loop within the ngWiget?

Comment: No, So should I need 2 loops for this, although there's only 1 data?

Comment: Well to me there are two child items, to display them one by one, you kind of need a loop , which is ngFor

Comment: Changed it to this but still not displaying the 2: <div *ngFor="let cdata of datas" [ngWidget]="cdata.childItems">List Child Items belonging to this Container</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have prop childItems, consist of two elements, you need to loop its items from **data** object instead of **datas** array.
So first *ngFor lets you run through **datas array**, and second *ngFor lets you run through **childItems** property **array**.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of datas">

  <div [ngWidgetContainer]="data" *ngFor="let item of data.childItems"> 
    <div [ngWidget]="item">List Child Items belonging to this Container</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what max2020 was doing wrong and how you solved his problem.